# Trying to install rebar3 in Android (via termux), multiple errors received

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I just downloaded the rebar3 package using wget from termux (android app), then I executed `chmod +x rebar3`.

Then, I run `nano rebar3` and I changed the first line from

`#!/usr/bin/env escript` to `#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/env escript`

But, when I try to install rebar3 running `./rebar3 local install`, I get the following errors

`./rebar3:5: cannot translate from UTF-8
./rebar3:5: cannot parse file, giving up
escript: There were compilation errors`